# Getting error in node js on running application

Tags: node.js

I am working on a project where I am using angular in frontend and node on the backend. Everything working fine on the local machine. But on production sometimes I am getting the below error on node side and everything stops working.
I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request module in my application
uncaughtException: nodeNC failed:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:35701
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 35701
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:35701` means you may not have started your server and it is not listening to the request

From [node.js docs:](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

> ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host.

This is expected. Since you are making HTTP requests using a synchronous package, which states in the docs:

> N.B. You **should not** be using this in a **production application**. In a node.js application you will find that you are **completely unable to scale your server**. In a client application you will find that **sync-request causes the app to hang/freeze**. **Synchronous web requests are the number one cause of browser crashes**. For production apps, you should use then-request, which is exactly the same except that it is asynchronous.

I would not personally use a package that has been updated for over two years, when during the same period node.js, JS, and browser technologies have updated their APIs rapidly.

The suggestion I can only give you is to use an asynchronous package, in line with the asynchronous architecture of node, that does that in a non-blocking, event-driven way. Choice is yours but bear in mind that you WILL run into these issues from time to time becasue of these design decisions.

If you need additional help, you need to show your server side code so we can redesign the HTTP handler to be asynchronous and eliminate the ECONNREFUSED error at runtime.

Does this help?

Comment: The error is quite clear to me. You will need to expand on the issue and provide more details. You say the error occurs  "sometimes"; when does it exactly happen? Do you have unstable internet connection at times? What is the difference between your dev and prod environment when you start the server?

Comment: similar to this https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-rpc/issues/3

Comment: that is a different type of error...please provide more details based on the questions above. Thank you

Comment: Updated answer. I strongly suggest you use an asynchronous package to make/receive HTTP requests or use node.js built-.in methods / APIs to handle these calls